# Pandas.str.extract multiple condition

Tags: pandas

how to put multiple reg expression in extract , i get syntax error.

[image]

I try so many things but doesn't help . please help and thanks.

update with my code in the below

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
# importing re for regular expressions 
import re 
# Creating the Series 
sr = ['New_York', 'Lisbon', 'Tokyo', 'Paris', 'Munich','11-11-11-11']
# Creating the index 
data = {'col1' : sr}
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data)
#mydf.column = ['col1']
mydf['extratcolumn'] = mydf['col1'].str.extract(r'([aeiou].)|(\d{2})')
```

Comment: Your sample code does not give an error to me. What is your desired output? How should column `extratcolumn` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The raw-string `r` must be connected with the regex string, without whitespaces. That's why you are getting the *invalid syntax* error.

You should use

```
.str.extract(r'([aeiou].)|(\d{4})')
```

Comment: still can't without space , ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: Try to edit your question with sample data and the code you used (not with an image, but copy and paste your actual code please)

Comment: @mytabi Anyway, your error makes me think that you have two columns with the same name

Answer (score 0):

you could use this method as well:

```
import re
x = ['aadsadasd','ewdwwe']
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df['m'],i = '',0
a = [m for m in df[0]]
for x in a:
    print(x)
    df['m'][i] = re.findall(r'([aeiou])|(\d{4})',x)
    i+= 1
```